# create decimal metadata properties in sharepoint online

Tags: metadata

I want powershell script to create decimal or refinabledecimal metadata properties as we have limitation of only 10 each. From UI I can create only text or bolean metadata but not decimal. How to create using powershell in online. anyone can provide me script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 'Number' Column type supports decimals natively. If you have reached the maximum limitations of that field then I would probably try to find an alternative method of managing your data (to ensure long term support).

You could possibly simulate floating point math with high precision using a calculated column.

Powershell is pretty good at reading data types but the resulting column may be formatted as a string... So you may have to convert it back to an integer within powershell.